# Audio volume control - MEDIA API

Tags: media-player, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

Phonegap has a Media API plugin to set volume of audio track in Android and iPhone. But I am not able to set and synchronize volume with device volume.

How can I set the device volume?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.setVolume